# Why can't I write messages/comments in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I'm scratching my head over this, but it says I need to be logged in, in order to write messages/comments, although I can access the chat page and read it!

Any clues as to why this might be so?

Comment: As a possible workaround, try logging in to either stackexchange.com or to any SE site where you have an account (associated with this one) that you haven't visited recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat is public (well, the parts *you* see anyway), so anyone can read messages.

Aside from that, you can be logged in to physics.SE but not chat.SE. You need to log in from [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global). If that doesn't work, you can see if your browser is incompatible(try the GlobalAuth test link on the page).

Otherwise, you can first log in normally [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fusers%2fchat-login), and then open chat.

Comment: Thanks, logging in via chat.se worked.